# Менеджер приложений против Центра приложений

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-software

В Ubuntu 16.04 по умолчанию запускается *Менеджер приложений* (он же "Ubuntu Software")
вместо *Центра приложений* (он же "Ubuntu Software Center"), как было в 14.04.

Оказывается, они показывают пользователю разные приложения:
Центр приложений знает gksu, а Менеджер приложений — нет!
[image: доказательство]

Это так и задумано, что *Менеджер приложений* (который "Ubuntu Software" из 16.04) фильтрует приложения?
Может, его надо как-то настроить?

**Upd:** До меня внезапно дошло, что *Менеджер приложений* дает в меню доступ к `Программы и обновления`. Это те же `Программы и обновления`, которые доступны из `Параметры системы` и из *Центра приложений* --> `Правка` --> `Источники приложений...`.

Получается, что обе программы используют те же репозитории.
Так почему отличаются результаты?

**Upd2.** Еще картинка: для Spyder3 Менеджер приложений дает оценку 3 звездочки от 3 голосовавших, несмотря на то, что по его же данным, 3 человека поставили ему 5 звездочек. [image: скриншот]

Comment: Может там репозитории разные?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, нашла списки репозиториев. Это "Программы и обновления" в обоих случаях.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [What is the difference between 'gnome-software' and 'ubuntu-software'](https://askubuntu.com/q/769129/3712)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Центр приложений* — старая GUI-программа для управления установленным ПО,
использовалась в Ubuntu до 16.04. Позже было решено отказаться от её
дальнейшей разработки в пользу *Менеджера приложений* из проекта Gnome. В
Ubuntu поставляется весьма модифицированная версия, благо внутренняя
архитектура этой программы заточена под это. Сама она написана на Си и
работает довольно шустро (в отличие от предыдущего центра приложений на
Python), имеет развитую систему плагинов.

Вместе с тем, эти программы кардинально различаются своим подходом. Менеджер
приложений Gnome (и Ubuntu) в качестве источника информации о ПО использует
[AppStream](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/appstream/docs/chap-AppStream-About.html) — БД с метаданными о компонентах программ в экосистеме СПО. Apt
регулярно загружает её с зеркала обновлений по команде `apt update` или
автоматически. В дистрибутивах основанных на Debian используется формат
[DEP-11](http://dep.debian.net/deps/dep11/).

По некоторым причинам в настоящий момент в этой базе в основном представлена
информация о программах, обладающих графическим пользовательским интерфейсом.
А из-за того, что по большей части эта база собирается автоматизированным
инструментом [appstream-generator](https://github.com/ximion/appstream-generator) на основе .desktop файлов, справедлива
импликация: "Если пакет с программой устанавливает .desktop файл со значком
для меню, это приложение можно будет найти в AppStream".

Но на самом деле, в *менеджере приложений* всё равно применяется фильтр — он
отображает в списке только программы с GUI, то есть те, что отмечены
`type=desktop-application`. Предполагается, что если вам нужна консольная
программа, гораздо проще поставить её напрямую с помощью Apt.

#### Выводы

*Менеджер приложений* использует AppStream — независящий от дистрибутива
список приложений в мире Linux и СПО. Тем не менее, пакеты ставятся из своих
обычных репозиториев, которые использует Apt.

*Центр приложений* использует инфраструктуру архива Debian или Ubuntu
напрямую, не прибегая к помощи AppStream или DEP-11.

#### Полезности

1. Можно получить доступ к базе данных AppStream, хранящейся на компьютере, из
   командной строки с помощью утилиты **appstreamcli** из пакета [appstream](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/appstream).
2. Сами списки в формате DEP-11 хранятся в каталоге `/var/lib/app-info/yaml`.
3. Впрочем, пользовательских обзоров вы там не найдёте (там только описания).
   Оценки программ загружаются с сервера reviews.ubuntu.com раз в три месяца,
   сразу все имеющиеся, комментарии — при открытии страницы с приложением. За
   это отвечает плагин `/usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_ubuntu-reviews.so`.

---

По поводу gksu: у меня подключен репозиторий Debian unstable, а gksu.desktop
перечислен в [yaml оттуда](https://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/dists/buster/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz), поэтому *Менеджер приложений* находит его в
поиске. Тем не менее, стоит воздержаться от использования этой утилиты — она
признана устаревшей и в будущем [будет удалена](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=867236).

Comment: 1. Я согласна, что *Центр приложений* тормозит, но все равно пока буду пользоваться им. Во-первых, мне не нравится, что мне фильтруют информацию, во-вторых, см. Upd2 вопроса.

Comment: 2. А чем можно редактировать системные файлы вместо gksudo?

Comment: Ну про оценки я уже упомянул, но повторюсь: звёздочки вверху загружаются раз в три месяца сразу для всех программ, гистограммы оценок (и комментарии) по каждому конкретному приложению загружаются при открытии страницы с программой. Возможно, в период между этими загрузками ситуация поменялась; хотя не стоит исключать какую-то незапланированную ошибку.

Comment: Про gksu и gksudo: в качестве замены предлагается использовать интерфейс PolicyKit, к сожалению, пока не все программы его поддерживают. Так или иначе в ближайшем будущем планируется переход на Wayland, а там эти утилиты не работают вовсе (как утверждает Jeremy Bicha).