# Переустановка Ubuntu с сохранением директорий пользователей

Tags: ubuntu

Как переустановить Ubuntu (16.04 Desktop) с сохранением информации пользователей?
На компьютере есть куча разделов и dual boot с каким-то старинным Windows-ом.
Live USB уже есть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Upd**: проверено и обновлено для 18.04.

Согласно [документации](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation#How_To_Reinstall_Ubuntu) Ubuntu, возможность переустановки с сохранением информации пользователей существует с версии 8.04 (Hardy Heron). Но там не очень понятно, что и как нужно делать. Здесь собрана информация из разных источников.

### План работы:

1. Подготовка — бэкап и сбор информации о системе.
2. Собственно переустановка.
3. Добавляем пользователей и устанавливаем недостающее.

**Бонус**: с какими проблемами я столкнулась.

Поехали.

### Подготовка

Мы создадим сборник данных о системе  и назовем его «шпаргалка». Часть информации из шпаргалки понадобится нам при переустановке, а другая часть — после.  Чтобы было удобно обращаться к шпаргалке с Live USB, можно сделать ее в виде черновика письма в почте и копировать все туда.

#### Разделы

Чтобы узнать, где какой раздел, запускаем команду

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=98279f46-f5ca-481f-b5dd-67a5d1790ecb /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=322d435c-f77e-4275-9a5c-ef50c6e68f24 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=17afbd07-eab0-4c66-99be-9b4a7a4f36f7 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Из вывода мы узнаём, что
rootу (`/`)  соответствует `/dev/sda3`
`/home` — `/dev/sda6`
`swap` — `/dev/sda5`
(Пугающее `errors=remount-ro` означает, что если root (/) смонтируется на чтение/запись с ошибкой, его надо перемонтировать (`remount`) [только для чтения (read only)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707118/what-do-the-fstab-mount-options-errors-remount-ro-mean). Тут все в порядке).

Подобную информацию можно получить также командой `lsblk`.

#### Пользователи

Для получения информации о пользователях запустим

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
```

В этом файле нас интересуют строки, упоминающие пользователей, типа

```
masha:x:1000:1000:Маша,,,:/home/masha:/bin/bash
...
dasha:x:1010:1010:Дарья,,,:/home/dasha:/bin/bash
```

Эти строки не обязательно идут подряд.
[Пользователей надо создавать в таком же порядке](https://askubuntu.com/a/630973/244413)  (по возрастанию номеров), с теми же «Именами пользователя» и паролями, тогда они получат свои домашние директории  и такие же номера, как раньше. Номера пользователей используются для кодирования прав доступа. «Полное имя» пользователя можно менять. 
Первый пользователь с номером 1000 создается при установке. Остальные — после.

Мне Ubuntu 16.04 не дала сохранить старый пароль при переустановке, потому что он вдруг оказался слишком простой. Это вызвало некоторые проблемы, о чем будет ниже.

#### Бэкап

- Сохраняем, как минимум, весь `/home`. Я сохранила, и он мне, к счастью, не понадобился.
- Я сделала список установленных программ и сохранила его. Но потом решила, что за много лет у меня там накопилась куча мусора и нет смысла устанавливать ее заново, а лучше устанавливать только то, что понадобится.
- За много лет у меня накопилось также  несколько кастомных настроек системы. Я помнила только про те, что находились в домашней директории. После переустановки  обнаружилось, что части настроек не хватает. Мои собственные вопросы на https://ru.stackoverflow.com помогли мне  восстановить пропажу. (Это была реклама `ruSO`:) 
  Тем не менее, хотелось бы иметь какой-то алгоритм, как искать файлы, измененные пользователем в /, кроме /home. Может, у кого есть идеи?

### Переустановка

Перед переустановкой на всякий случай проверяем, что у нас достаточно места в разделе /(root) и что мы выбрали правильную версию из 64 или 32 бит.

Запускаем Ubuntu с Live USB. Открываем шпаргалку со списком разделов.
Запускаем установку Ubuntu.

В окне «Тип установки» выбираем **Something Else** (Другой вариант)

В следующем окне выбираем разделы, которые относятся к Ubuntu, кроме `swap` (его Ubuntu находит сама).
В данном случае монтируем
`/dev/sda3` в `/`
`/dev/sda6` в `/home`
При желании можно отформатировать `/`.
**`/home` форматировать не надо!**
Что будет, если все находится в одном разделе? Желающие могут попробовать (не форматируя `/`) и отписаться в комментариях. Вдруг получится?
В любом случае, часть директорий в `/` будет стерта и перезаписана при установке.

При установке (вос)создаем пользователя 1000 из файла `/etc/passwd`.

### После переустановки

- В терминале запускаем
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
- Если вы что-то меняете в **подкачке**, например, вместо раздела делаете файл, сейчас самое время это сделать. Команда `free -h` проверит, что все работает.
- Даже если на языковой панели видны нужные **языки**, они могут быть недоустановлены. Поэтому открываем «Параметры» -> «Регион и язык» и
  нажимаем «Управление установленными языками». Открывается окошко «Язык системы» и говорит, что языки установлены не полностью. Нажимаем, что мы хотим их установить.
- Создаем остальных **пользователей** по списку.
  Если номера пользователей идут не подряд, например: {1000, 1001, 1003}, то нужно создать временного пользователя с пропущенным номером (1002), а потом удалить. Каждый пользователь должен получить свой старый номер.
- Устанавливаем нужные **приложения**.
- Проверяем, что у всех все работает.

### Проблемы

Здесь я опишу, с какими проблемами я столкнулась (16.04).

#### Поломались LibreOffice и терминал

У одного из пользователей возникли следующие проблемы:
 - В Документах показывают, что есть файлы `*.ods`, но они не открываются в LibreOffice.
 - Пытаюсь запустить LibreOffice из терминала — не открывается терминал.
 - Также не получается поменять пароль, находясь в этом счету.

Подсказку дало сообщение об ошибке, написанное кракозябрами —
надо было зайти в `Язык системы`  и установить недостающий язык.
Почему возникла эта проблема?
При обычной установке сначала устанавливается язык, а затем он назначается главным для пользователя и на нем создаются документы. Здесь же получилась учетная запись и документы в ней на неустановленном  языке. Очевидно, в Ubuntu не предусмотрено даже сообщение об ошибке для такого странного случая.

После этого я добавила  в разделе **После переустановки** пункт про языки.

#### Поломался бэкап

При запуске системного бэкапа появилось сообщение об ошибке
 **Failed to execute child process ("Duplicity") (No such file or directory)**
Оказывается, Ubuntu устанавливает `deja-dup`, но не устанавливает его бек-энд.
Решение:

```
sudo apt install duplicity
sudo apt-get install python-gi
```

Это баг [1641423](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1641423), исправлен с версии 17.10.

#### "Unlock your login keyring"

Меня стало преследовать окно  с требованием **"Unlock your login keyring"**.
Причем оно отказывалось принимать мой пароль от учетной записи, а какой еще пароль ему давать?
Ответ нашелся на [askubuntu 1](https://askubuntu.com/a/224777/244413), [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/187720/244413).
Запускаем *Gnome Keyring Manager* с логичным названием `seahorse` (с терминала или из Dash)
В левом меню нажимаем правой кнопкой мыши на слово `Login` (под `Passwords`), и выбираем `Change Password`. Появляется окошко смены пароля.
Пароль, который оно приняло, был мой старый (до переустановки) пароль от Ubuntu. Я просто поменяла его на новый, и больше окно "Unlock your login keyring" меня не беспокоило.

#### Пропал *Центр приложений*.

После переустановки у меня есть только *Менеджер приложений* (он же "Ubuntu Software"), который устанавливается в 16.04,
а [любимого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706731/185618)  *Центра приложений* (он же "Ubuntu Software Center"), как было в 14.04, больше нету :(
Я решила ничего с этим не делать. Скоро все равно переходить на 18.04, может, там будет лучше.
Если буду сильно скучать по *Центру приложений* (который "Ubuntu Software Center" из 14.04), буду искать, откуда его устанавливают.